# javascript array basics

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to improve my javascript an running into somewhat of a dead end here.

```
var schemes = {
    "own" : {
        "creatures" : ["creature1","creature2","creature3","creature4"],
        "spells" : ["spell1","spell2","spell3","spell4"],
        "items" : ["item1","item2","item3","item4"]
    },
    "enemy" : {
        "creatures" : ["creature1","creature2","creature3","hidden"],
        "spells" : ["spell1","spell2","hidden","hidden"],
        "items" : ["item1","item2","item3","hidden"]
    }
};
```

This is my array.

Im then trying to do a for each (as I know from php), but it seems javascript thinks schemes is an object and thus unable to do a:

```
for (var i=0;i<schemes.length;i++) {
 //code 
}
```

What am I missing? schemes.length says undefined

Comment: hello, var schemes is not Array, It is JSON object, check json.org and http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp, it will help you, thx

Comment: @KPBird there is no such thing as a "JSON Object".  JSON is a "serialisation format", which happens to look somewhat like a JS "Object literal", which is what `schemes` actually is.

Comment: @KPBird: **NO**, it's not a JSON object. `schemes` is a JavaScript object created through an object literal. Please see http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`schemes` is indeed an "object", and as such has no `.length`.

You can use `Object.keys(schemes)` to obtain an array of the keys, or:

```
for (var key in schemes) {
    var el = schemes[key];
     ...
}
```

Comment: thx a lot - coming from php so you can understand my confuseness :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the fact that `schemes` is actually an object, not an array.

Consider the following:

```
myobject = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 } // this is an object

myarray = [ 1, 2, 3 ] // this is an array
```

And what you can do with these variables:

```
for (var key in myobject) {
    console.log(key + ": " + myobject[key]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    console.log('Value at index ' + i + ':' + myarray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Schemes is an object.  I think you want to make it an array of objects.

```
var schemes = [{
    "own" : {
        "creatures" : ["creature1","creature2","creature3","creature4"],
        "spells" : ["spell1","spell2","spell3","spell4"],
        "items" : ["item1","item2","item3","item4"]
    },
    "enemy" : {
        "creatures" : ["creature1","creature2","creature3","hidden"],
        "spells" : ["spell1","spell2","hidden","hidden"],
        "items" : ["item1","item2","item3","hidden"]
    }
}];
```

You can then traverse the array as follows:

```
for (var i=0;i<schemes.length;i++) {
  alert(schemes[i].creatures[1]); //alerts creature1 (2x)
}
```